# Coingate callback post method data not seen

Tags: node.js, callback

I am trying to integrate crypto pay with coingate to my nodejs app but the callback post method has a req.body which is empty. Please do anyone have any idea on how to retrieve the order data so that I can use it for another api call. I have looked on the entire req object and couldn't see the order data.